# Finding the limit of $\frac{xy+yz+zx}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$ as $(x,y,z)$ approach $(0,0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I used polar coordinates and found the limit to be $0$. However I tried using successions $\{x_k\},\{y_k\},\{z_k\}$, who all approach 0, but I got stuck.

Can someone help, pls?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you know Cauchy-Schwarz? What about the squeeze theorem?

Comment: I know both CS and squeeze theorem for single variable.

Comment: Hint: $|yz+zx+xy| \le |y||z|+|z||x|+|x||y| \le x^2+y^2+z^2$ and replace the numerator.

Comment: I substituted $x= \rho \sin(\phi)\cos(\theta),\ y=\rho\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)$, and $z=\rho\cos(\phi)$

Comment: @EduardoKuri spherical coordinates work, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|\frac {xy} {\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}}| \leq |\frac {xy} {\sqrt {x^{2}}}| =|y| \to 0$ Similarly, $|\frac {yz} {\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}}| \to 0$ and $|\frac {zx} {\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}}| \to 0$. Add these three.

Comment: And then I just choose $\varepsilon$/3 for the bound in the limit for x, y, z, right?

Comment: The summands each have finite limits, so you are allowed to evaluate them separately and sum them.

Comment: @EduardoKuri Yes, you can use the fact that $\frac {\epsilon} 3+\frac {\epsilon} 3+\frac {\epsilon} 3=\epsilon$.